# db error in node js mongoose ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS}

Tags: mongoose

**error in mongoose dbs**

E:\Language\Web\Node Js\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:291
const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at Timeout._onTimeout (E:\Language\Web\Node Js\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:291:38)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) {
'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
address: 'localhost:27017',
type: 'Unknown',
hosts: [],
passives: [],
arbiters: [],
tags: {},
minWireVersion: 0,
maxWireVersion: 0,
roundTripTime: -1,
lastUpdateTime: 162220460,
lastWriteDate: 0,
error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at connectionFailureError (E:\Language\Web\Node Js\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:387:20)
at Socket. (E:\Language\Web\Node Js\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:310:22)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 27017
},
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
},
topologyVersion: null,
setName: null,
setVersion: null,
electionId: null,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
primary: null,
me: null,
'$clusterTime': null
}
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

link of image

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S807n.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgABE.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z73dU.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYV63.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to your main file of .js

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';  to change only one localhost = 0.0.0.0

new look like

const url = 'mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017';

or

const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';

Comment: `0.0.0.0` isn't localhost.

Comment: try to run code with use localhost but not working when use 0.0.0.0 its work or 127.0.0.1

Comment: @NitishSingh, could you change "localhost = 0.0.0.0" to " localhost to 0.0.0.0"? In the context of servers, 0.0.0.0 can mean "all IPv4 addresses on the local machine".

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You must also provide the code and explain what problem you're facing. Secondly, provide the error you got properly.

In node.js v18, localhost uses ipv6 address (`::1`), and by default mongodb localhost doesn't have ipv6 enabled. That's why you're facing this issue.

If you want to use ipv4 localhost address (`127.0.0.1`),

1. **Either** replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/somedb")
```

2. **OR** use `family: 4` parameter. This tells the node.js localhost to use ipv4 address.

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/somedb", { family: 4 })
```

**OR**

If you want to use the ipv6 address, then just start `mongod` with `--ipv6` as argument. This enables mongodb ipv6 address.

```bash
mongod --ipv6
```